# Emgu Cv and 16 bit grayscale images

Tags: c#, compatibility, emgucv, grayscale

Does Emgu Cv offer any kind of support for working with 16 bit grayscale images? (working with c#).
If it doesn't is there any kind of easy-ish workaround for that?
thanks in advance

On [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Depth_and_Color_as_Generic_Parameter) it says "Any attempts to use a 16-bit floating point or non-grayscale image as a mask will results a compile time error!" and I'm a bit confused as to what it means.

My confusion comes from the following experiment:

I did try to open and save an image, however, I noticed that after opening and saving an image, the resolution went **from 16bpp to 8bpp** (tiff) - but no error/exception. I'm not sure whether that comes from a lack of support from the library or I'm just not saving the image properly using image.Save()

The code to open the image is:

```
my_Image = new Image<Gray, ushort>(Openfile.FileName);
```

and to save the image:

```
my_Image.Save(fName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, as must have been your search before asking : [yes](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Creating_Image).

If that doesn't answer, or you're asking because you encountered problems, stuff a little more your question, explaining what your problem is, and what you tried. If not, read the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: Well I did try, however, I noticed that after opening and saving an image, the resolution went from 16bpp to 8bpp (tiff). I'm not sure whether that comes from a lack of support from the library or I'm just not saving the image properly using image.Save()

Comment: Ok, now that looks like a real question. Searching further more, according to some posts (http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=296 ) and documentation (http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/01adb181-753d-0b14-f867-fee707f20b75.htm ) it seems that working with 16 bits images is problematic, at least if you need to save them. But I could't find any information about a workaround, sorry.